# Extract parts of html using regex

Tags: html, regex

I have a simple requirement to extract text in html. Suppose the html is

```
<h1>hello</h1> ... <img moduleType="calendar" /> ...<h2>bye</h2>
```

I want to convert it into three parts

```
<h1>hello</h1>
```

```
<img moduleType="calendar" />
```

```
<h2>bye</h2>
```

The aim is to extract text in two categories, simple html and special tags with <img moduleType="Calendar".

Comment: /me sigh... another "how to parse html with regex" question...

Comment: What language are you coding in?  There's likely a better solution than regular expressions, many languages have DOM parsers.  Also, you might want to accept answers on some of your other questions to improve the quality/quantity of future answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: [Check the answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html+regex).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that; HTML can be broken in many beautiful ways.  Use [beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the language and context you are using. I do something similar on my CMS, my approach is first find tags and then attributes.

Get tags

```
"<img (.*?)/>"
```

Then I search through the result for specific attributes

```
'title="(.*?)"'
```

If you want to find all attributes you could easily change the explicit title to the regex [a-z], or non-whitespace character, and then loop through those results as well.

Comment: Fighting against the downvotes you'll get -- Welcome to SO ;-) Include known problems/limitations in your answer. HTML parsing with regular expressions is almost always stomped on.

Answer (score 0):

I actually try to do similar thing as asp.net compiler to compile the mark up into server control tree, regular expression is heavily used by asp.net compiler. I have a temporary solution, although not nice, but seems ok.

```
//string source = "<h1>hello</h1>";
string source = "<h1>hello<img moduleType=\"calendar\" /></h1> <p> <img moduleType=\"calendar\" /> </p> <h2>bye</h2> <img moduleType=\"calendar\" /> <p>sss</p>";
Regex exImg = new Regex("(.+?)(<img.*?/>)");

var match = exImg.Match(source);
int lastEnd = 0;
while (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[2].Value);
    lastEnd = match.Index + match.Length;
    match = match.NextMatch();
}
Console.WriteLine(source.Substring(lastEnd, source.Length - lastEnd ));
```